# Error App Store Connect: 'ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist' & 'ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement' [Flutter]

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store-connect, info.plist

I am trying to upload a new version of our app on the App Store Connect. In our old version we are already using push notification and hence, the certificate for Apple Push Services is already active and added in the Apple Developer Portal (as shown in the screenshot below). When we uploaded our previous version of the app to App Store Connect, there was no issue. However, now when I am trying to upload our new version of the app to App Store Connect using Xcode, there is no error shown in the Xcode side and uploading is successful (as shown in the screenshot below).

When I go back to the App Store Connect to check my uploaded build version so that I can submit it for review, it is saying that the build is being processed (as shown in the screenshot below). After sometime I receive an email from the App Store Connect mentioning that our build version has the following issues (detailed email is provided at the end of this question):

> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist
>
> ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement

For our app's latest build version it is mentioned that ITMS-90683 error for Info.plist (shown below) is missing description for **NSContactsUsageDescription, NSCalendarsUsageDescription, NSAppleMusicUsageDescription, NSMotionUsageDescription, NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription & NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**. However, in our app, which is built with Flutter framework, we are not using any of these permissions specifically.

My Questions are as follows:

1. How can I fix the ITMS-90683 error when I am not using any of these
   permissions explicitly in our app such that the build version can be
   uploaded for review successfully?
2. Since, the Apple Push Services' certificate is already added to Apple Developer portal how can I fix the ITMS-90078 and submit the app for review?

Info.plist content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>AppName</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to upload image</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to upload image</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to upload image</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>Launch Screen2</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Screenshot of "Signing & Capabilities" of my project:
[image]

Screenshot of successful upload of the build version from Xcode:
[image]

Screenshot of the App Store Connect where the new build version is being processed:
[image]

Screenshot of Apple Developer Portal with Apple Push Services Certificate enabled, which is used by previous version fo the app:
[image]

Email from App Store Connect regarding the error:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
> [APP NAME] 2.0.1 (4). Please correct the following issues, then upload
> again.
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSContactsUsageDescription key with a
> user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your
> app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the
> App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose
> string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
> APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
> APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
> developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
> their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with
> a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why
> your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to
> the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose
> string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
> APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
> APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
> developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
> their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with
> a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why
> your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to
> the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose
> string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
> APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
> APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
> developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
> their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSMotionUsageDescription key with a
> user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your
> app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the
> App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose
> string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
> APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
> APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
> developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
> their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription
> key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and
> completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps
> submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to
> include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs,
> they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app
> might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can
> contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a
> version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to
> make you aware of them:
>
> ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears
> to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app
> signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
> entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
> make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
> Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
> Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
> entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment
> entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is
> intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications
> in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the
> entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key
> with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely
> why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted
> to the App Store that access user data are required to include a
> purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may
> reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not
> use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact
> the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version
> of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
> key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and
> completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps
> submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to
> include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs,
> they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app
> might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can
> contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a
> version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fix the ITMS-90683 error when I am not using any of these permissions explicitly in our app such that the build version can be uploaded for review successfully?

This part of app review doesn't care if you're actually using these features. All they check is whether the app has code to do so (which yours obviously does) and comes with the required purpose strings. To solve this, you basically have two options:

- figure out which pieces of code/library/whatever you have in your app that brings this baggage along, and get rid of it, or
- live with the baggage and provide the required purpose strings.

> Since, the Apple Push Services' certificate is already added to Apple Developer portal how can I fix the ITMS-90078 and submit the app for review?

The problem is not with the certificate, but with the app's entitlement, which you're not showing. Make you you have the push notification entitlement enabled in your app.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For Apple Push Services, I haven't changed the push notification entitlement in our app since the previous version was uploaded and submitted successfully. So, how come its an issue for this new version?

Comment: `but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. ` - make 100% it does.

Comment: I have also edited my question to reflect the Info.plist content. Thank you for your help on this. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Entitlements are stored in a .entitlements file. To view/edit, go to "Signing & Capabilities" in your project.

Comment: In "Signing & Capabilities" of my Runner (iOS) project my Apple Developer profile is added and Profile has the following 4 entitlements: Application Identifier, keychain-access-groups, get-tase-allow and com.apple.developer.team-indentifier. What changes can I make here to make it work?

Comment: I have also updated my question with the content of "Signing & Capabilities" for my project.

Comment: Click "+" and add Push notifications.